# Tornado HTTP proxy server not catching HTTPS request

Tags: python, tornado

I have set up a tornado HTTP server which is working as a proxy server.
I am using the python requests library to use it as a proxy server.
When I try to fetch HTTP url's with it, it works fine. But it isn't intercepting HTTPS requests.

The proxy server part:

```
class ProxyServer(HTTPServerConnectionDelegate):
    def start_request(self, server_conn, request_conn):
        print('In start request')
        return ClientDelegator(request_conn)

    def on_close(self):
        pass

    def client_send_error(self):
        self.write('Error happened.')
        self.finish()


def main():
    server = HTTPServer(ProxyServer())
    server.bind(8888)
    server.start(0)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The requests part:

```
import requests


url = 'https://example.com'
proxy = {'http' : '127.0.0.1:8888'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

When I use *http://example.com*, the connection starts as 'In start request' gets printed. However, when I use *https://example.com* then the connection doesn't start. The *ProxyServer* doesn't enter *start_request*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `proxy` variable only specifies a proxy for `http`, not `https`. You need to set the proxy for both protocols separately.